# date/time math in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, date

This is from a WHERE clause in HQL:

```
(current_timestamp() - c.m_some_time) >= :3000) // finding 3 seconds and older
```

It doesn't work.

I saw many questions regarding this subject, but they all avoid using `current_timestamp()` and put a Java Date() instead (using `setString()`), which is **wrong for me as I need precision**.

Another approach I saw is deriving a dialect and registering my own function. This one seem to be too blown.

**Any way to make a simple time math and compare it to a simple value of milli/seconds, in pure built-in HQL?**

Another issue that I'm curious about is **why does the above WHERE clause does pass HQL's checks?** I mean, this is a part of an HQL query which works (when the other WHERE clauses are valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually there doesn't seem to be an answer so the best is to extend `Dialect` and register a function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variables order in your query from:

```
current - from_db >= 3000
```

To:

```
from_db <= (current - 3000)
```

You will calculate value in your query:

```
calculated_timestamp = current_timestamp() - 3000;

c.m_some_time <= :calculated_timestamp
```

Comment: `(c.m_some_time <= current_timestamp() - 3000)` doesn't work.

Comment: current_timestamp() - 3000 should go as a string or parameter to your query.

Comment: it does. The above is the EXACT way I write it in the HQL statement. Doesn't seem to subtract dates.

Comment: @SteveEbersole exactly as it sound. Having `(c.m_some_time <= current_timestamp() - 3000)` in a WHERE clause, while knowing *for sure* that this condition should pass, that's it. Does it work for you or something? Did anyone test the above?

Comment: Rather than trying to be argumentative maybe you should try being respectful of people attempting to help you?  Does the SQL generated return what you expect when run in the database?  You have to understand that Hibernate is just passing this to the database.  And the specifics of support for date arithmetic is extremely varied.  3000 in your query is interpreted as an INTERVAL datatype according to ANSI SQL; however, the "precision" of that as a raw literal is not defined.  You think it is 3000 milliseconds, but to Oracle that is 3000 days (IIRC); on your db, dunno.

Comment: @SteveEbersole I was not aware I sound argumentative - thanks for the feedback and apologies for showing such an attitude - even if it's not intended. Well, I understand that each dialect might treat this differently although I would count on Hibernate to unify it. Anyway I'm using H2 database (for dev of course). Bottom line is that this doesn't work and I'd gladly hear a solution for something that sounds SO SIMPLE to do, and so TRIVIAL.

Comment: I think I know what is problem. Don't pass current_timestamp() as a string. Calculate this in java: long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - 3000; and pass this calculated value into query.

Comment: @alexey28 that's something I'm trying to avoid, as said.. I wish to use the database server's time.

Comment: And did you try directly in the database and then directly through JDBC?

Comment: @SteveEbersole yes although `current_timestamp()` is not the keyword in H2 DB but it's `NOW()`.

Comment: H2 recognizes both: http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp  If it works through JDBC, then sorry but I simply dont believe you that the same query would not work through Hibernate.  You *sure* you took the query Hibernate sends to the database and ran that directly against H2?

Comment: *took the query Hibernate sends to the database and ran that directly against H2* never said I did that. I can't see what Hibernate translates the HQL to, or at least the values in it (you know, there are those '?').

Comment: `show_sql` is on as said above. Anyway I went with a custom dialect, so I want to thank you both Steve and Alexey for at least trying to help out here. Really appriciated!!